# Return Codes from PeopleCode Exec Function

Tags: unix, peoplecode

I am attempting to kick off a third party program using EXEC command in PeopleSoft.  It is returning error code 127. When I kick the program off from Unix command line, I get no error.  Does anybody know what code 127 is? Or have a list of all the return codes?

Comment: You should ask the developers of that third party program for the exact meaning of "127" or any other code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is likely the Unix shell return code, in which case 127 is "command not found".
See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

You may need to make sure your Exec call is specifying the correct path, relative or absolute, or that any expected environment variables are available.  Possibly test with a simple program to see if calling through Exec is successful at all.  On the server it would run under the ID that started the app server, and may be sourced differently than an individual user.  If using relative paths I believe it would start in $PS_HOME.

If you can provide the code snippet someone may be able to also provide other suggestions.